# PHP Detect if One of www & non-www Redirect to The Other

Tags: php, html, redirect

I need to write a PHP script to detect if either www redirects to non-www, or non-www redirects to www version of the site. In the process I also need to detect if it's a 301 or 302 redirection. The result should be the redirection code (301 or 302) or Null if the redirection does not exist.

The scope of this is to detect if www and non-www are seen as two different sites or if one redirects to the other and what kind of redirection it is.

Can someone please help me with the script?

Thanks :)

Comment: Redirection status codes are reported to the client by the server. They are not reported to PHP. In other words: It could be PHP doing the redirecting, but it is not something you can 'detect' with PHP.

Comment: I would like to access the site through PHP script and detect from it, maybe through CURL and detect like that.

Comment: I see, yes, if you use CURL as the client to another site, you should be able to detect any redirection taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a http status code:

```
// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check HTTP status code
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    case 200:  # OK
      break;
    default:
      echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
  }
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
```

I didn't make this up, it is copied directly from the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

See example #2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it. I can arrive up to that point, but would need help in forming the script and output the proper result. Can you help in that please?

Comment: You have to try something yourself first. We do not write code for you, we help you when you get stuck. Present the code you've made so far, and tell us why you cannot make it do what you want it to do. When you do, your question might also get up-voted instead of down-voted. Everybody who programs struggles with problems, it is par for the course. You *have* to put in some effort yourself. Only by working through problems yourself,  you will become a better programmer.